# Unable to get the key value while json parsing in swift

Tags: ios, swift, jsonparser, jsonencoder

I am using below code to parse json from API

```
struct ResourceInfo: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let type: String
    // let department: String. -> Unable to get the value for department
}

struct CustomerInfo: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let country: String
    let resources: [ResourceInfo]

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name
        case country
        case resources
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.country = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .country)

        let resourcesDict = try container.decode([String: ResourceInfo].self, forKey: .resources)
        //print(resourcesDict.map { $0.key })
        self.resources = resourcesDict.map { $0.value }
    }
}

static func parseJson() {
        let json = """
        {
          "name": "John",
          "country": "USA",
          "resources": {
            "electronics": {
              "id": "101",
              "type": "PC"
            },
            "mechanical": {
              "id": "201",
              "type": "CAR"
            },
            "science": {
              "id": "301",
              "type": "CHEM"
            }
          }
        }
        """
        let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CustomerInfo.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
        dump(result)
    }
```

Output:

```
Optional(JsonSample.CustomerInfo(name: "John", country: "USA", resources: [JsonSample.ResourceInfo(id: "201", type: "CAR"), JsonSample.ResourceInfo(id: "301", type: "CHEM"), JsonSample.ResourceInfo(id: "101", type: "PC")]))
  ▿ some: JsonSample.CustomerInfo
    - name: "John"
    - country: "USA"
    ▿ resources: 3 elements
      ▿ JsonSample.ResourceInfo
        - id: "201"
        - type: "CAR"
      ▿ JsonSample.ResourceInfo
        - id: "301"
        - type: "CHEM"
      ▿ JsonSample.ResourceInfo
        - id: "101"
        - type: "PC"
```

Could someone help me get the value department like `electronics`, `mechanical` & `science`? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You throw away the information in the line `resourcesDict.map { $0.value }` because you ignore the `keys`.

My suggestion is to add a temporary helper struct, decode that and map the dictionary to `ResourceInfo`  with both `key` and `value`

```
struct Temp : Decodable {
    let id, type: String
}

struct ResourceInfo {
    let id: String
    let type: String
    let department: String
}

struct CustomerInfo: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let country: String
    let resources: [ResourceInfo]

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case name, country, resources }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.country = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .country)

        let resourcesDict = try container.decode([String: Temp].self, forKey: .resources)
        self.resources = resourcesDict.map {
            ResourceInfo(id: $1.id, type: $1.type, department: $0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You beat me to the same answer by 1 minute!

Comment: Thank you for sharing the Temp struct. This works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, where you decode `ResourceInfo` initially with just its CodingKeys,
then remap the results with the dictionary keys as the `department`,
as shown in the SwiftUI example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var customerInfo: CustomerInfo?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let customer = customerInfo {
                Text(customer.name)
                List(customer.resources) { resourse in
                    Text(resourse.department)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            parseJson()
        }
    }
    
    func parseJson() {
        let json = """
            {
              "name": "John",
              "country": "USA",
              "resources": {
                "electronics": {
                  "id": "101",
                  "type": "PC"
                },
                "mechanical": {
                  "id": "201",
                  "type": "CAR"
                },
                "science": {
                  "id": "301",
                  "type": "CHEM"
                }
              }
            }
            """

        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(CustomerInfo.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
            print("\n---> result: \(result)\n")
            customerInfo = result
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
}

struct ResourceInfo: Identifiable, Decodable { // <-- here
    let id: String
    let type: String
    var department: String = "" // <-- here
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {  // <-- here
        case id
        case type
    }
}

struct CustomerInfo: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let country: String
    let resources: [ResourceInfo]

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name
        case country
        case resources
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.country = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .country)

        let resourcesDict = try container.decode([String: ResourceInfo].self, forKey: .resources)

        // -- here
        resources = resourcesDict.map { ResourceInfo(id: $0.value.id, type: $0.value.type, department: $0.key) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty lies in the fact that the data structure you want doesn’t map directly with the hierarchy in the JSON. The department name is a key to a dictionary containing the id and type values. If you want to collapse that information into a single struct then this is one solution. There may be smarter ways to do this. I just added a separate structure for decoding the id and type:

```
struct ResourceInfoDetails: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let type: String
}

struct ResourceInfo: Decodable {
    let department: String
    let id: String
    let type: String
}

struct CustomerInfo: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let country: String
    let resources: [ResourceInfo]

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name
        case country
        case resources
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.country = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .country)

        let resourcesDict = try container.decode([String: ResourceInfoDetails].self, forKey: .resources)
        self.resources = resourcesDict.map { ResourceInfo(department: $0, id: $1.id, type: $1.type) }
    }
}
```